# Alamofire protocol return array of model objects

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using alamofire and it's serializing protocols. I have a model and its working great. Now, exactly how do I get an array of that model from these methods?

```
static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [DataObject] {

        var daos: [DataObject] = []
        if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for contentRepresentation in representation {
                if let content = DataObject(response: response, representation: contentRepresentation) {
                    daos.append(content)
                }
            }
        }
        return daos
    }

class func populateData() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .responseCollection { (response: Response<[DataObject], NSError>) in

         //response.result.value how do i pass this to my viewcontroller?
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a JSON response from the request?

If so, you may be able to try something along the lines of this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {
        response -> () in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let object):
            if let urlResponse = response.response {
                let dataObjects = collection(response: urlResponse, representation: object)
                // Pass the objects back to your view controller here
            }
            break

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Error: ", error)
            break
        }
    }
```